# Mongodb Aggregation Not In Select

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I have a problem with mongodb aggregation not in.

I have a collection "user" with data:

```
{
    "_id": "1234",
    "name": "Antony"
},
{
    "_id": "1235",
    "name": "Michael"
}
```

and collection "verify" which is related with "user" collection:

```
{
    "_id": "111",
    "user": "1234",
    "status": "true"
},
```

I want to select user who is user_id not in verify collection. And return data its should be:

```
{
    "_id": "1235",
    "name": "Michael"
}
```

Because Michael is not verified user.

How can i do that query with mongodb aggregation not in? Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using `$lookup` then `$match`

```
[
  {
    $lookup:{
     from: "verify", 
     localField: "_id", 
     foreignField: "user", 
     as: "res" 
    } 
  }, 
  { $match : { res: [] }} 
]
```